# Read only mode in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have cloned human pose estimation keras model from this link [human pose estimation keras](https://github.com/michalfaber/keras_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation)

When I try to load the model on google colab, I get the following error

code

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 

last)
<ipython-input-29-bdcc7d8d338b> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 model = load_model('model.h5')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    417     f = h5dict(filepath, 'r')
    418     try:
--> 419         model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
    420     finally:
    421         if opened_new_file:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
    219         return obj
    220 
--> 221     model_config = f['model_config']
    222     if model_config is None:
    223         raise ValueError('No model found in config.')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py in __getitem__(self, attr)
    300             else:
    301                 if self.read_only:
--> 302                     raise ValueError('Cannot create group in read only mode.')
    303                 val = H5Dict(self.data.create_group(attr))
    304         return val

ValueError: Cannot create group in read only mode.
```

Can someone please help me understand this read-only mode? How do I load this model?

Comment: I had the same error for my network and found a solution. [coremltools troubleshoots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54466679/7064856)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example Git gist created on Google Collab for you: https://gist.github.com/kolygri/835ccea6b87089fbfd64395c3895c01f

As far as I understand:

> You have to set and define the architecture of your model and then use model.load_weights('alexnet_weights.h5').

Here is a useful Github conversation link, which hopefully will help you understand the issue better:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6937

Comment: How does one 'set and define the architecture of your model'?

Comment: e.g. model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue and solved this way

**store** the `graph\architecture` in `JSON` format and `weights` in `h5` format

```
import json

# lets assume `model` is main model 
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model_in_json.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(model_json, json_file)

model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

then need to `load model` first to `create` `graph\architecture` and `load_weights` in model

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import model_from_json
import json

with open('model_in_json.json','r') as f:
    model_json = json.load(f)

model = model_from_json(model_json)
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

Comment: For me, this answer fills in a couple massive gaps by resolving the "load_model" problem via the JSON rather than confusing the .h5 with the model as so many other answers did. Now this is all coming together. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I used `callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` to save the weights and I had a similar error. I found out that there is a parameter called `save_weights_only`

If I set `save_weights_only=True`, then when I use load_model() to load the model in another process, it will raise the 'Cannot create group in read only mode.' error.

If I set `save_weights_only=False`(which is the default), then I can use load_model() to load the model and use it to do prediction, without compiling the model first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `model.save(model_path+'Model.h5')` and then `keras.models.load_model(model_path+'Model.h5')`, this way, you will not need to build and compile the model before load the weights, as `model.save` creates the architecture in dict inside the `.h5` file.

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution is you have to load the save model in the same way it is saved

for example you had created a model like this

```py
# Build the model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=10,
                    epochs=5,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.1)

#save model
model.save("model.h5")
```

so if you want to load this model for prediction you have to follow the same steps

```py
from keras.models import load_model
# Build the model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# load model
model.load_weights('model.h5')

prediction = model.predict( ''' data to predict ''')
```

Comment: Why do you import load_model then not use it? Your answer uses load_weights also and doesn't answer the ops question about load_model.