# How to load Keras model from .cfg file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, yolo

I have 2 files - `my_model.cfg` (which is in Darknet format, I guess) and `trained_weights.h5` and I want to do something like `model.load_model()`. But I can't simply load weights cuz i get 
`ValueError: Cannot create group in read only mode.`
How can I reproduce model's structure from that `.cfg` file?

*UPDATE*:This question is not a duplicate - I have already read what means "read only mode*, and I am asking exactly what is described in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214077/8495108), but depending on my configuration - I have no json file, but .cfg. And I can't save my model with usual .save() method cuz that is custom model, so it throws error smth like " you cant use this method cuz your model is implemented by python methods... "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read only mode in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212672/read-only-mode-in-keras)

Comment: @mkos, this is not a duplicate - read my update. I have already read that question - mine is different.

Comment: The only possibility I see here is to manually code a model that matches the one in the .cfg, or to find some custom code that produces keras models from .cfg files.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro but that is a YOLO model - it has ~255 layers :/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the Darknet pre-trained models, and have both the cfg and weights, you can use the [Keras implementation](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3) of YOLOv3.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229367/7553185) answer for reference.

Comment: yep, that is exactly the implementation which I am using now :)