# How to load darknet YOLOv3 model from .cfg file and weights from .weights file, and save the model with the weights to a .h5 file?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, yolo

I have downloaded the .weights and .cfg file for YOLOv3 from darknet (link: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) I want to create a model and assign the weights from these files, and I want to save the model with the assigned weights to a .h5 file so that I can load the .h5 model into Keras by using keras.models.load_model().

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the instructions given in [this](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3) repository. This is basically the keras implementation of YOLOv3 (Tensorflow backend).

- Download YOLOv3 weights from YOLO website.
- Convert the Darknet YOLO model to a Keras model.

  `python convert.py yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights model_data/yolo.h5`

As you have already downloaded the weights and configuration file, you can skip the first step. Download the `convert.py` script from repository and simply run the above command.

**Note**: Above command assumes that `yolov3.cfg`, `yolov3.weights` and `model_data`(folder) are present at the same path as `convert.py`.

Answer (score 0):

For people getting error from this try changing the layers part in 'convert.py'
Not sure if it was version problem but changing the way converter.py file was loading 'keras.layers' solved all errors for me