# Keras - Proper way to extract weights from a nested model

Tags: keras, hdf5, transfer-learning

I have a nested model which has an input layer, and has some final dense layers before the output. Here is the code for it:

```
image_input = Input(shape, name='image_input')
x = DenseNet121(input_shape=shape, include_top=False, weights=None,backend=keras.backend,
layers=keras.layers,
models=keras.models,
utils=keras.utils)(image_input)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='dense_layer1_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)        
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='dense_layer2_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax', name='image_output')(x)
classificationModel = Model(inputs=[image_input], outputs=[output])
```

Now If say I wanted to extract the densenets weights from this model and perform transfer learning to another larger model which also has the same densenet model nested but also has an some other layers after the dense net such as:

```
image_input = Input(shape, name='image_input')
x = DenseNet121(input_shape=shape, include_top=False, weights=None,backend=keras.backend,
layers=keras.layers,
models=keras.models,
utils=keras.utils)(image_input)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='dense_layer1_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)        
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='dense_layer2_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense_layer3_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(num_class, activation='sigmoid', name='image_output')(x)
classificationModel = Model(inputs=[image_input], outputs=[output])
```

Would I need to just do: `modelB.load_weights(<weights.hdf5>, by_name=True)`? Also should I name the internal densenet? and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, before using the nested model, have it into a variable.
It gets a lot easier to do everything:

```
densenet = DenseNet121(input_shape=shape, include_top=False, 
                       weights=None,backend=keras.backend,
                       layers=keras.layers,
                       models=keras.models,
                       utils=keras.utils)

image_input = Input(shape, name='image_input')
x = densenet(image_input)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
......
```

Now it's super simple to:

```
weights = densenet.get_weights()
another_densenet.set_weights(weights)
```

---

## The loaded file

You can also print a `model.summary()` of your loaded model. The dense net will be the first or second layer (you must check this).

You can then get it like `densenet = loaded_model.layers[i]`.

You can then transfer these weights to the new dense net, both with the method in the previous answer and with the `new_model.layers[i].set_weights(densenet.get_weights())`

Comment: I see where you are going here, but lets say, and sorry I wasn't more clear, I have used a checkpoint, saved the weights (and the model) of modelA. I only have an hdf5 file from some previous experiment. Would I be able to load the weights from this file to a new densenet? like this: another_densenet.load_weights('hdf5File.hdf5'). ModelA has a densenet nested in it.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Your proposal will also work, as long as you guarantee that the new dense net has the same layer names as the old dense net.

Comment: I agree, but I have to have modelA instantiated somehow. For example, right now I do not have this loaded model, just the hdf5 file.

Comment: Load model a from the file

Comment: Thanks! I assume this is the correct way to load the model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55624161/1726404

Comment: `from keras.models import load_model`, `model = load_model(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to go about this is to use the model you have trained itself without trying to load the model weights. Say you have trained the initial model (copied and pasted from the provided source code with minimal edits to variable name):

```py
image_input = Input(shape, name='image_input')
# ... intermediery layers elided
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
output = Dropout(0.5)(x)
model_output = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax', name='image_output')(output)
smaller_model = Model(inputs=[image_input], outputs=[model_output])
```

To use the trained weights of this model for a larger model, we can simply declare another model that uses the trained weights, then use that newly defined model as a component of the larger model.

```
new_model = Model(image_input, output) # Model that uses trained weights

main_input = Input(shape, name='main_input')
x = new_model(main_input)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense_layer3_image')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(num_class, activation='sigmoid', name='image_output')(x)
final_model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[output])
```

If anything is unclear, I'd be more than happy to elaborate.