# ERROR Cannot create group in read-only mode

Tags: python, flask, keras

We are creating a series of applications that use a learned model created by subjecting a facial image to machine learning to determine who the user looks like when the facial image is uploaded.

ERROR Cannot create group in read-only mode.
How do you think we can solve this problem
Here's my code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
```

I think this code has a problem

```
#model.save('model.h5',  include_optimizer=False)
model = load_model('./model.h5', compile=False)
```

The code below seems to be okay

```
classes = ["秋元真夏","生田絵梨花","齋藤飛鳥","白石麻衣","堀未央奈",]
num_classes = len(classes)
image_size = 64

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "static"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

# 顔を検出して顔部分の画像（64x64）を返す関数
def detect_face(img):
    # 画像をグレースケールへ変換
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # カスケードファイルのパス
    cascade_path = "face.xml"
    # カスケード分類器の特徴量取得
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)
    # 顔認識
    faces=cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(10,10))

    # 顔認識出来なかった場合
    if len(faces) == 0:
        face = faces
    # 顔認識出来た場合
    else:
        # 顔部分画像を取得
        for x,y,w,h in faces:
            face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # リサイズ
        face = cv2.resize(face, (image_size, image_size))
    return face



graph = tf.get_default_graph()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    global graph
    with graph.as_default():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('ファイルがありません')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('ファイルがありません')
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
                filepath = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)

                 #受け取った画像を読み込み
                img = cv2.imread(filepath, 1)
                # 顔検出して大きさ64x64
                img = detect_face(img)

                 # 顔認識出来なかった場合
                if len(img) == 0:
                    pred_answer = "顔を検出できませんでした。他の画像を送信してください。"
                    return render_template("index.html",answer=pred_answer)
                # 顔認識出来た場合
                else:
                    # 画像の保存
                    image_path = UPLOAD_FOLDER + "/face_" + file.filename
                    cv2.imwrite(image_path, img)


                img = image.load_img(filepath, grayscale=True, target_size=(image_size,image_size))
                img = image.img_to_array(img)
                data = np.array([img])

                result = model.predict(data)[0]
                print(result)
                predicted = result.argmax()
                pred_answer = classes[predicted] + "に似ています"
                message_comment = "顔を検出出来ていない場合は他の画像を送信して下さい"

                return render_template("index.html",answer=pred_answer, img_path=image_path, message=message_comment)

        return render_template("index.html",answer="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
    enter code here
```

The error code of the terminal.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kk/Desktop/sample-app/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = load_model('./model.h5', compile=False)
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 584, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 270, in _deserialize_model
    model_config = h5dict['model_config']
  File "/Users/kk/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py", line 318, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError('Cannot create group in read-only mode.')
ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212672/read-only-mode-in-keras

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read only mode in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212672/read-only-mode-in-keras)

Answer (score 0):

First define your model, and use `load_weights()` instead of using `load_model`.

Here's an issue link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6937

Comment: Thank you.
I also saw the link.
However, if I rewrite as the following code, I got another error.

Comment: model = load_model_weights('./ model.h5', compile = False)

NameError: name 'load_weights' is not defined

You probably need to redefine your model,
Does it mean that the code I wrote is not defined?

Comment: You forgot to import load_weights, use `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_weights`

Comment: Thank you.
I was able to solve it safely.